# display show from join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 models (**RailwayStation**, Route & join table `RailwayStationsRoute`)

```
class RailwayStationsRoute < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :railway_station
  belongs_to :route 

class Route < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :railway_stations_routes
  has_many :railway_stations, through: :railway_stations_routes

class RailwayStation < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :railway_stations_routes
  has_many :routes, through: :railway_stations_routes
```

my task: in view Route (**show.html.erb**) display list of stations by ordinal number (`station_number` - integer field in join table)

when I wrote code:

```
<% @route.railway_stations.each do |station| %>
<%= station.railway_stations_routes.inspect %><%= station.title %>
```

display:

```
ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<RailwayStationsRoute id: 2, railway_station_id: 2, route_id: 1, station_number: 2>]Saint-Petersburg
```

where we can see `station_number`

But if I change Inspect to `station_number`.. display:

```
undefined method `station_number' for #<RailwayStationsRoute::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fc3cffe3ef0> Saint-Petersburg
```

because i do not have station_number method in railwayStation model

next I have created scope in join table:

```
scope :ttt, -> { select('railway_stations.*, 
           railway_stations_routes.station_number') }
```

& changed code in view:

```
<%= station.railway_stations_routes.ttt %><%= station.title %>
```

display:

```
#<RailwayStationsRoute::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation:0x007fc3cff15190>Saint-Petersburg
```

Question: How to make this result in number format(`station_number`) ?

(like code below)

```
2 Saint-Petersburg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<% @route.railway_stations.select("railway_stations.*,railway_stations_routes.station_number").each do |station| %>
  <%= station.station_number %><%= station.title %>
<%end%>
```

Comment: hi ! Work ! (applied your decision) Thank you! is it possible to decide by scope?

Comment: create your scope method on railway_stations model 
`scope :ttt, -> { select('railway_stations.*, railway_stations_routes.station_number') }`
and then call it 
`<% @route.railway_stations.ttt.each do |station| %>`
if this is working means, accept this as a answer.